# Can't change the style of a submit input type?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, css

I have a membership plugin which makes a custom login page. I want to change the hover style for the submit button. I tried to inspect the element to know which style i should change but i can't find the style. Here is a link to the login page [login](http://cleopatrahairnailsbeautyspa.com/login/). please check the login button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fault is from the following code, change the colors or remove it.

```
.xoouserultra-wrap a.xoouserultra-button:hover, input[type=submit].xoouserultra-button:hover, input[type=submit].xoouserultra-button:focus, input[type=button].xoouserultra-button:hover, input[type=button].xoouserultra-button:focus, .xoouserultra-wrap a.xoouserultra-button:active, input[type=submit].xoouserultra-button:active, input[type=submit].xoouserultra-button:active, input[type=button].xoouserultra-button:active, input[type=button].xoouserultra-button:active {
    border: 1px solid #1278b2;
    background-color: #1278b2;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1278b2), to(#1391da));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1278b2, #1391da);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1278b2, #1391da);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1278b2, #1391da);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1278b2, #1391da);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px -1px #fff;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 10px;
}
```

Hope it works, good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much, but would you please tell me how did you find the styles

Comment: Inspect with Google Chrome, right-click element and choose :Hover.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.